# Kdtree c++ erase and insert low perfomance

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

In my game i use libkdtree++. My approach is on every move of npc or player, erase it from tree and insert new position. Something like this:

```
void Map::updateEntityPos(Entity& e)
{
    map_lock.lock();
    map_duplet.set_data(e.getLastPos(), &e);
    entity_tree->erase_exact(map_duplet);
    entity_tree->optimise();
    map_duplet.set_data(e.getPos(), &e);
    entity_tree->insert(map_duplet);
    entity_tree->optimise();
    map_lock.unlock();
}
```

But i found that this piece of code slow down perfomance to zero even with 100 npc's. How i can improve position update perfomance for finding of nearest entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting or removing from a collection each time something moves is a sure-fire way to bottleneck the performance of your program in an instant.

Split your world up in to a grid, and keep a reference of what characters are a particular square of the grid at any one point.  When you want to find out entities that are near to another, you can define a circle around the centre of the entity in question, check which squares overlap this circle and only check entities that fall within those 4 squares to determine which is within the circle.

Comment: I though that with kdtrees i will improve perfomance... Maybe i really need to simplify approach

Comment: @DenisErmolin, I suspect they do improve performance to look things up (a good thing), but consistently erasing and re-inserting is not the way to go about it.